# Using an absolute path when setting the webdriver for Internet Explorer in Protractor on Windows

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, selenium, protractor

I am trying to run automated tests using Protractor. my protractor.cong.js file is as follows.

```
exports.config = {
specs: ['tests/**/*.test.js'],
params: {
    colors: false
},
multiCapabilities: [
    { 'browserName': 'firefox', 'proxy': { 'proxyType': 'autodetect'} },
    { 'browserName': 'chrome' },
    { 'browserName': 'internet explorer', 'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true }
],
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe']
```

}

This all works well and good but I would much prefer if the path for the webdriver was absolute rather than relative. For example:

```
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Selenium\IEDriverServer.exe']
```

Is this possible? I have checked the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) but it has not offered a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was that I was trying to use window style paths or unix style paths rather than an amalgimation of the two. the correct way to write it is:

```
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe']
```

NOT

```
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Selenium\IEDriverServer.exe']
```

(the slashes are the other way round)

Comment: have you tried to get the browserName? if yes. how? browser.getCapabilities() doesn't work, it returns promise.